# ZF2 BjyAuthorize get user highest role

Tags: zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

I've got a little issue with BjyAuthorize: I can retrieve all the user's roles but I would like only the highest one.

For example, if a user is admin, I can retrieve all his roles (guest, user and admin) but would like to display only admin.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define what you mean with highest. In case of permission inheritance then the one with no parent has the least permissions. But that only works when they are related. So, if they are related like `admin` -> `user` -> `guest` where the arrow can be read like "inherits permissions from", then it's very likely (deny rules not taken into account) that `admin` has the most permissions because the user has not been assigned another role that inherits from `admin`.

When f.e. `admin` inherits permission from `user` and `guest` is not related to `user` or `admin` at all, then it will become more complex.

- `admin` -> `user`
- `guest`

To determine which one has more rights (the naming of the role is obvious, but not to your application), you have to compare the permissions of `guest` with the permissions of `admin`.

It's not easy to do, and I doubt it's what you want, since it's possible that a parent can have more permissions. F.e. when a deny rule has been applied to the inheritor.

Comment: I know that I could create a method to find the role with no parent as I am using inheritance. It would work but it's over complicated as you noted. Would BjyAuthorize still work if I put only one role per user? The highest one obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is old, but in case it's useful for anyone:
If you have a user role, and an admin role that inherits permissions from user, you don't have to give someone who is an admin both roles, just the admin role. They will automatically get the permissions from the user group, too; that's what the inheritance is for.